# "Meet in the middle" with SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have an interesting question regarding SSH. I have a machine at school that I'd like to be able to access from elsewhere. It's behind a firewall/NAT, so I can't get at it directly. I have a leased web server that I can SSH into from anywhere. I was wondering if I could do some voodoo with port forwarding to get to my machine at school via the web server. I think this comes down to whether you can do SSH "backwards," which may or may not be possible.

Basically:
Machine A can access Machine B
Machine C can also access Machine B
How can Machine A access Machine C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to **"backward" SSH** there's **[Reverse Remote Shell](http://www.cycom.se/dl/rrs)** that [I've been using](http://blog.dvl.pl/article/2009/03/14/reverse-shell-access/) for a while in a similar situation.

But here, some things should be clarified first:

1. **What kind of access** do you need? Are we talking about **SSH only** or you meant something else?
2. What's about this **web server** (*B*)? Can it access the destination (*C*) directly without problems (which is not possible from *A*)? Or is it only a problem of **unknown/dynamic IP** of the source machine (*A*)?

I presume that in a standard situation you're able to initiate outgoing connections from *C* without restrictions, and all new inbound traffic is filtered, right?

**UPDATE:**

In that case you could use **Reverse Remote Shell** to connect from *C* (school) to *B* (SSH account). Then logging in from *A* (home) to *B* over SSH you grab the reverse console access to *C*. Plus side of this is it should work on almost any configuration.

**Major drawbacks:**

1. It's SSH only plus things you can do when you have local access to *C*.
2. You implicitly trust *B* (that your session won't be stolen).

This is a bit cumbersome. It would be much easier to use **SSH port forwarding** for this, but that is sometimes blocked by universities/schools (at least from my experience). Please see if you can use it in your situation. Then an easier and more elegant solution should be possible.

Comment: If I can get SSH, I can presumably tunnel anything else I need. Both A and C don't have externally accessible IP addresses, otherwise this'd be a good deal easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do port forwarding using SSH to get access to your machine at school. What you'll have to do is:

1. From the machine at school, you issue the following command:

   ssh -R port_on_server:localhost:local_port user@server
2. From the machine at home you do:

   ssh -L local_port:locahost:port_on_server user@server

Now, you can access your `local_port` at your home machine and will be forwarded to `local_port` at the machine at school. For example, if local_port is 80, you would be able to type http://localhost/ on your web browser and access the web server running at the machine at school.